# Can 2 players mount a horse?

Tags: dnd-5e

Can 2 players mount a horse? If so, Can the player not controlling the mount cast spells o shoot an arrow? If the horse doesn't have a saddle there is any difficult to do this?

Comment: And welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about us and how we operate. You can also visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more info, too. And don't worry about duplicates, those are good so others can find the same thing even if it's asked a little differently.